# Spring Data Mongodb POJO mapping

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I know that Spring Data MongoDB is a POJO centric model for interacting with a MongoDB DBCollection. But in my case the POJO mapping is somewhat irrelevant.For example the JSON string that I need to store as a single document in a collection is as follows

```
columns:[
{
name:"xyz"
age:12
},
{
name:"abc"
age:34
},
{
name:"pqr"
age:76
}
]
```

What can be the equivalent POJO mapping in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can achieve it through this mapping (If I understood your question correctly):

```
class Person {
    String name;
    int age;
}

class Outer {
    @Field("columns")
    List<Person> persons;
}
```